# Parsing JSON ARRAY

Tags: java, json, arrays

I'm working on json parsing and I got a problem.
This is my JSON:

```
"cards":[
{
"id":"bgyr6gh5yr6154",
"checkItemStates":[
],
"closed":false,
"desc":"",
"due":"2012-06-13T10:00:00.000Z",
"idBoard":"4v454g5r1515",
"idChecklists":[
],
"idList":"16562562526",
"idMembers":[
"2848f4g85t15"
],
"idShort":15,
"labels":[
],
```

I can get all information in the JSON Array cards (e.g "closed", "due",...)

I'm doing for instance,

```
JSONArray msg2 = (JSONArray) all.get("cards");
```

then

```
String boardId = (String) monobjet.get("closed");
```

and it works fine!

BUT

I don't know how to get "idMembers" !
Any idea, because it's array in a array?

```
JSONArray msg2 = (JSONArray) all.get("cards");
```

then

```
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < size2; i2++) {
                  myobject =  (JSONObject) msg2.get(i2);

                  listTemp2.add(jsonObecjtToMyData(myobject));
              }


String boardName = (String) monobjet.get("name");
```

Comment: What do you mean "can't get". do you get an error? what error? what code do you use? I assume you are not casting the array you are looking for to `String` ? Please show the code that doesn't work, what you expect to happen and what actually did happen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't have an error, I just don't know how get this particular array : "idMembers":[
"2848f4g85t15"
],

Answer (score 0):

For complex json objects such as the one given, I will strongly recommend [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) which will do all the task for you.For example:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
Map map = gson.fromJson(inputField.getText(),Map.class);
```

Now, map conatains all the things you need, so iterate through the map get the idMembers put it in a list and while you are putting it typecast it to string or any datatype that is fit.

You can individually typecast but not an array. So this will compile and run:

```
public class MainApp {
    public Object obj[]={"foo","loo"};
    public Object obj2 = "soo";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainApp mainApp = new MainApp();
        String name = (String) mainApp.obj2;
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Some food for thought:

1. JSONArray is an object. How would the json handler that you are using would know that it is a JSONArray or list?
2. Can we do something like this?:

   ```
   public class MainApp {
       public Object obj[]={"foo","loo"};
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           MainApp mainApp = new MainApp();
           String name[] = (String[])mainApp.obj;
           for(String str : name){
               System.out.println(str);
           }
       }}
   ```

Please use gson and save yourself a lot of pain.Also for complex pojos you can use [ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html).